# How to turn off microphone in ActionAcript3

Tags: actionscript-3, microphone

How to turn off microphone in AS3? Sample code is below. I want to turn off (close) microphone   by calling closeMicrophone() function.

```
var microphone:Microphone = null;
function openMicrophone():void{
    if(Microphone.isSupported){
        Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);
        microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
        if(microphone != null){
            microphone.setLoopBack();
            microphone.setSilenceLevel(5, 2000);
            }else{
            trace('No microphone found!');
            }
        }else{
        trace('The Microphone class is not supported on this system!');
        }
    }
function closeMicrophone():void{
    // Here, I want to turn off microphone.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to disable the microphone loopback, right? Then just call again the `setLoopBack` method with `false` as parameter.

```
function closeMicrophone():void{
    microphone.setLoopBack(false);
    microphone = null;
}
```